# jQuery IF statements to calculate fees based on two drop downs and a textbox field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is an example of a fee calculator that will run a live tally of fees (jQuery) based on what the user selects and answers. I am trying to figure out how to create many IF statements to calculate fees based on two drop downs and a textbox field.

What I am trying to accomplish is a jQuery IF function that calculates with an `onChange="calculateTotal()"` when the user will select there birth month (calculate months) this will calculate how many months from now until there next birthday. But I need to have the IF function based on the vehicle drop down (vehiclebody) and the weight (ew) that is entered those three items will decide the price. Like the examples below and snippet below.

For example (three scenarios):
 
[1] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight under 2499 the price will be 28.10 added to the running fee calculator. 
[2] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight between 2500 and 3499 the price will be 36.10 added to the running fee calculator. 
[3] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight greater than 3500 the price will be 46.10 added to the running fee calculator.

So long story short I want a IF function that calculates `onChange="calculateTotal()"` and `var titleFees = getProofOfOwnership() + (New IF Function);` depending on (vehiclebody) chosen & (ew) entered & then IF (monthsToGo) is equal to 4 thru 12 its such and such price. If (monthsToGo) is 1,2,3,13,14,or 15 the price will be prorated so it will have its own price as well.

If its 1 month away they require the user to pay for that month and the full year so 13 months, but if its 2 months they let the user choose either 2 months or 14 months same with 3 months or 15 months (as you see on the calculate months drop down) but once it is 4 months (they pay the full amount no matter if its 4-12 months)

What is horrible is I will have to figure out like 50 different combinations of this so hopefully it will be easy for me to understand with my extreme lack of knowledge with jQuery.

Any help will be greatly, greatly, greatly, appreciated!! :)

http://jsfiddle.net/fzy9yev3/15/

See snippet below:

```js
//Calculate Months
(function() {
    var monthsToGo;
    var Fee = makeStruct("monthSect vehicleBody ewSect price");
    var fees = [
        new Fee(/*monthSect*/2, /*vehicleBody*/0, /*ewSect*/0, /*price*/45.10),
        new Fee(3, 1, 0, 55.10),
        new Fee(4, 2, 0, 65.10),
        new Fee(13, 3, 0, 75.10),
        new Fee(14, 4, 0, 85.10),
        new Fee(15, 5, 0, 95.10)
    ];

    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#month2, #month3').hide();
    });
    
    $(document).on('change', '#ownership input', function(){
        calculateTotal();
        //statedropDown($(this).val());
    });
    
    $(document).on('change', '#month1', function() {
        // ignore blank options
        if ($(this).val() == '') { return; }
        
        var vehicle = $('#vehiclebody').val();
        var ew = $('#ew').val();
        var ewSect = 0;
        var monthSect = 0;
        var titleFees = 0;
        
        if(vehicle == '' || ew == ''){
            alert('Please enter Vehicle Type and/or Empty Weight');
            $(this).val('');
            return;
        }
        
        var today = new Date();
        var birthdate = new Date();
        birthdate.setMonth($('#month1').val());

        monthsToGo = (today.getMonth() < birthdate.getMonth())
            ? birthdate.getMonth() - today.getMonth()
            : (12 - today.getMonth()) + birthdate.getMonth()
        ;
        
        $('#month2').hide();
        $('#month3').hide();

        if (monthsToGo == 1) {
            this.monthsToGo = 13;
            alert(this.monthsToGo);
        } else if (monthsToGo == 2) {
            $('#month2').show();
        } else if (monthsToGo == 3) {
            $('#month3').show();
        } else {
            this.monthsToGo = monthsToGo;
            alert(this.monthsToGo);
        }
        
        if(monthsToGo >= 4 || monthsToGo <= 12){
            monthSect = 4;
            //Set monthsToGo to 4 if it is in this range for the linked list so
            //categorizing is easier
            //6 possibilities for dates -- 2, 3, 4, 13, 14, 15
        }
        else monthSect = monthsToGo;
        
        switch(vehicle){
            case 0://2dr
            case 2://4dr
            case 4://convertible
            case 5://van
                if(ew < 2500) ewSect = 0;
                else if(ew >= 2500 && ew < 3500) ewSect = 1;
                else if(ew >= 3500) ewSect = 2;
                break;
            case 1://pickup
                if(ew < 2000) ew = 0;
                else if(ew >= 2000 && ew <= 3000) ewSect = 1;
                else if(ew > 3000 && ew <= 5000) ewSect = 2;
                break;
            case 3://trucks
                if(ew > 5000 && ew < 6000) ewSect = 0;
                else if(ew >= 6000 && ew < 8000) ewSect = 1;
                else if(ew >= 8000 && ew < 10000) ewSect = 2;
                else if(ew >= 10000 && ew < 15000) ewSect = 3;
                else if(ew >= 15000 && ew < 20000) ewSect = 4;
                else if(ew >= 20000 && ew <= 26000) ewSect = 5;
                else if(ew > 26000 && ew < 35000) ewSect = 6;
                else if(ew >= 35000 && ew < 44000) ewSect = 7;
                else if(ew >= 44000 && ew < 55000) ewSect = 8;
                else if(ew >= 55000 && ew < 62000) ewSect = 9;
                else if(ew >= 62000 && ew < 72000) ewSect = 10;
                else if(ew >= 72000 && ew <= 8000) ewSect = 11;
                break;
        }
        
        console.log('Month Section (monthSect): ' + monthSect + '; Vehicle: ' + vehicle + '; EW Section (ewSect): ' + ewSect);
        
        for(var i = 0; i < fees.length; i++){
            console.log('infor');
            if(fees[i].monthSect == monthSect && fees[i].vehicleBody == vehicle && fees[i].ewSect == ewSect) {
                titleFees = getProofOfOwnership() + fees[i].price;
                console.log('Title Found! ' + titleFees);
                $('#totalPrice').text('Estimated Transfer Fees $' + titleFees);
                break;
            }
        }
        
    });

    $('#month2, #month3').on('change', function() {
        this.monthToGo = $(this).val();
        alert(this.monthToGo);
    });
    
}($))

//Fee Calculator
//Setting Proof of Ownership Prices
 //Set up an associative array
 var title_prices = new Array();
 title_prices["MCO"]=68.25;
 title_prices["FL Title"]=78.25;
 title_prices["OOS Title"]=88.25;
 
 // Proof of Ownership Radio Buttons
function getProofOfOwnership()
{  
    var proofOfOwnership=0;
    //Get a reference to the form id="form"
    var theForm = document.forms["form"];
    //Get a reference to the title the user Chooses name=ownerShip":
    var ownerShip = theForm.elements["ownership"];
    //Here since there are 4 radio buttons ownerShip.length = 4
    //We loop through each radio buttons
    for(var i = 0; i < ownerShip.length; i++)
    {
        //if the radio button is checked
        if(ownerShip[i].checked)
        {
            proofOfOwnership = title_prices[ownerShip[i].value];
            //If we get a match then we break out of this loop
            //No reason to continue if we get a match
            break;
        }
    }
    //We return the proofOfOwnership
    return proofOfOwnership;
}
function calculateTotal()
{

    var titleFees = getProofOfOwnership();
    


    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='block';
    divobj.innerHTML = "Estimated Transfer Fees $"+titleFees;

}

function hideTotal()
{
    var divobj = document.getElementById('totalPrice');
    divobj.style.display='none';
}

function makeStruct(names) {
  var names = names.split(' ');
  var count = names.length;
  function constructor() {
    for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      this[names[i]] = arguments[i];
    }
  }
  return constructor;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="form">
    <div id="ownership">
        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" required="yes" message="Please select proof of ownership." value="MCO"/>Manufacturer's Statement of Origin&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><br/>
        <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" value="FL Title"/>Florida Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label><br/>
                <label class='radiolabel'><input type="radio"  name="ownership" value="OOS Title"/>Out-of-state Certificate of Title&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
        </div>

    <br/>
    <br/>

<label for='month1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Calculate Months:</label>
<select name="month1" id="month1" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Month</option>
    <option value="0">January</option>
    <option value="1">February</option>
    <option value="2">March</option>
    <option value="3">April</option>
    <option value="4">May</option>
    <option value="5">June</option>
    <option value="6">July</option>
    <option value="7">August</option>
    <option value="8">September</option>
    <option value="9">October</option>
    <option value="10">November</option>
    <option value="11">December</option>
</select>
<select name="month2" id="month2" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
</select>
<select name="month3" id="month3" size="1">
    <option value="">Choose an Option</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
</select>
    <br/>
    

<select name="vehiclebody" id="vehiclebody" required="yes" message="Please select body." size="1">
    <option value="">Choose a Vehicle</option>
    <option value="0">2Dr</option>
    <option value="1">Pickup</option>
    <option value="2">4dr</option>
    <option value="3">Truck</option>
    <option value="4">Convertible</option>
    <option value="5">Van</option>
</select>

<label for="ew">Empty Weight:</label>
    <input type="text" name="ew" id="ew"/>
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <div id="totalPrice"></div>
</form>
```

Comment: So I'm trying to understand completely. You have three variables set from the form, and you want to calculate a price based off their selection? How is the price calculated?

Comment: The price should calculate based on there choices. Once they answer vehicle body and enter the weight they will then choose there birth month and it will tell them theres (that number of months till there birthday)

Comment: This will automatically calculate because I will somehow how to make all the different scenarios fees and all, I am trying to get the basics first though from 4-12 months

Comment: because as of right now once they choose December then they can either choose between 2 or 14 month or if they chose January they can chose between 3 to 15 months

Comment: basically where I am trying to begin because as you see this can become very complex is with these three scenarios: [1] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight under 2499 the price will be 28.10 added to the running fee calculator. [2] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight between 2500 and 3499 the price will be 36.10 added to the running fee calculator. [3] if 4-12 months from now is chosen, as well as 2dr vehicle with a weight greater than 3500 the price will be 46.10 added to the running fee calculator.

Comment: You want this to run based on month change and take the current values of vehicle body and weight?

Comment: Yes, The order it asks them is vehicle body then vehicle weight and then months and I was thinking have the onchange for the months when they choose there month from the drop down

Comment: How can you have 13+ months till their next birthday :D And this question needs a lot more explanation :)

Comment: But whats also a pain is really that drop down is 3 drop downs did you test it in the snippet?

Comment: Well if its 1 month away they require the user to pay for that month and the full year

Comment: but if its 2 months they let the user choose either 2 or 14 same with 3 or 15 but once it is 4 months (they pay the full amount no matter if its 4-12 months)

Comment: What? the other 2 dropdowns aren't even showing though. Think you can make this into a fiddle instead? might be easier to work with.

Comment: they show when December or January is chosen

Comment: and it will cycle through as the dates change its how many months from now until the month they have chosen

Comment: do the prorates change for different cars? also something to think about... what happens if the user picks a month but no car/weight has been entered? those values are undefined. So you may want to think about just updating as the form as a whole is changed

Comment: Another question... if you are using jQuery why are you using Javascript to fire certain functions, like onchange? why not just use jQuery throughout?

Comment: sorry I would put them both on one but one makes you use no wrap in <head> and the other makes you use onLoad

Comment: because it was already JavaScript and there was wayyyy to much to go back and redo :)

Comment: this was just a piece from it lol

Comment: You wouldn't need to redo anything. Just simply call your JavaScript functions from inside your jQuery `change` function.

Comment: can you add classes to the HTML code or is it set in stone?

Comment: where is your `statedropDown` function? it doesn't exist so it keeps pushing errors

Comment: Yes u can add classes

Comment: Just remove that for now those are on the radio buttons for onchange for a different drop down menu I forgot to remove those from the example I'm sorry just delete the onchange on those three radio buttons

Comment: @Adjit I adjusted the fiddles and posted them in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63867/discussion-between-vicki-and-adjit).

Comment: I will give the 200 to the person who takes her final code and cleans it all up! I want something very similar to this but I feel like hers is all over the place. So whoever cleans it all up will get the bounty.
Final code is in her chat, please provide a fiddle showing it works properly.

Comment: @ZaneZ this should have been the bounty description rather than *Looking for an answer drawing from credible and/or official sources.*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would suggest taking an approach that not only cleans up your code, but will also make things easier to calculate, test, validate, and add new features. A little bit of cleaning up can go a long way in making your application easier to extend and debug, but more importantly, for your situation, a little bit of cleanup will help you calculate the values you are looking for and solve your problem in a straight-forward way.

### Suggestion #01 : Organize your Code

Right now you have a few functions that are trying to do too much at once. Functions are easier to test and debug if you keep them simple and let each function "specialize" in something specific. For example, in your `on.("change")` handler for your `$("#month1")` drop-down, you are trying to do everything at once, which is where you are running into trouble. Instead, you will want to assign an `.on("change")` handler to your `#month1` drop-down, which will determine if `#month2` or `#month3` need to be shown, and then assign a separate `.on("change")` handler to collect the value from these two drop-downs. And while you are at it, you will want to break out any "specialized" functionality into its own function to keep your code clean. 

**An example of your `#month1` change handler that is simply trying to do too much at once:**

```
$(document).on('change', '#month1', function() {
    // 1. Stop if Empty Weight or Vehicle Type are Blank
    // 2. Get the user's birth month
    // 3. Calculate the number of months until the user's Birthday
    // 4. Calculate the monthSect value
    // 5. Calculate the ewSect value
    // 6. Lookup the Proof of Ownership Fees
    // 7. Lookup prorated Title Fees
});
```

Instead, of having this one function try to preform all of these tasks in one place, you are better off moving any "specialized" functionality into simple, digestible functions that each have a clear purpose. You can create function names like:

```
// Lookup the Prorated Fee
getProratedFeeFromFeeList(monthSect, vehicleBody, ewSect);

// Get the "Payment Plan Details" based on user's birth month
getPaymentPlanDetailsBasedOnBirthMonth(birthMonth);

// Lookup the ewSect (Empty Weight Section)
getWeightSectionFromVehicleClassAndEmptyWeight(vehicleClass, emptyWeight);
```

*Note: I like to use long, descriptive function names so that the purpose of the function is very clear, which improves the readability of the code. Long function names like these don't add a whole lot of extra typing if you use a code editor that has good code-completion features, but for me, I personally enjoy the benefit of highly-readable, self-documenting code.*

### Suggestion #02 : Keep your form values stored in one place.

Continuing on with suggestion #1, since your form is meant to have a "live-tally", it will save you a lot of headaches if you have a system set in place to keep a snapshot of your form's values at all times. You can do this easily with a Javascript object.

**This is handy for a number of reasons:**

1. It makes all the form values "globally available" **without
   cluttering up the global namespace**.
2. It makes your form values easy to "calculate" within your
   `calculateTotal()` function since you only ever have to query this
   one object for values to plug into your equation.
3. You have a "live-snapshot" of your entire form at all times. This is
   handy for testing, debugging, validating, or printing form results to the console or the browser.
4. It allows you to keep adding features/values to your fee calculator app
   without breaking up your workflow.
5. By having a full snapshot at all times, it will be easier to spot
   errors in functionality and see how your individual inputs are
   affecting the other inputs or the overall calculation.

So I would create a global object called `FC` (short for "Fee Calculator") to store all the values you need in order to run your fee calculations. Create this "Fee Calculator Object" like this:

```
var FC = FC || {};
```

Now this `FC` object will be available to all your functions that have access to `FC`'s scope. Adding values to your `FC` object can be done in one of two ways:

```
// First method: In FC's Declaration
var FC = { monthSect: 0, vehicleBody: null };

// Second Method: Using dot notation
var FC = {};
FC.monthSect = 0;
FC.vehicleBody = null;
```

*Note: Keep in mind that you can always use dot notation to assign values to a object that has already been declared, so a combination of these two methods is perfectly valid.*

Now you can update and read values from your `FC` object using dot notation, for example:

```
// Get the monthSect variable
var monthSect = FC.monthSect;

// Assign or update FC.monthSect
FC.monthSect = someNewValue;
```

## My Solution to Your Problem

Using some of the suggestions I mentioned above, this is how I would go about solving your problem:

#### Step #01 : Each form input listens for changes, updates `FC` and calls `calculateTotal()`

```
// When the user updates the #month2 or #month3 dropdown
// Update FC.monthSect 
$(document).on('change', '#month2, #month3', function() {
    FC.monthSect = $(this).val();
    calculateTotal();
});

// When someone updates the Empty Weight value
// update FC.emptyWeight 
$(document).on('change blur keyup', '#ew', function() {

    var emptyWeight = $(this).val();
    FC.emptyWeight = emptyWeight ? emptyWeight : null;

    var vehicle = $('#vehiclebody').val();

    if (vehicle && emptyWeight) {
        FC.ewSect = FCUtils.getWeightSectionFromVehicleClassAndEmptyWeight(FC.vehicleBody, FC.emptyWeight);
         FCUtils.getProratedFeeFromFeeList(FC.monthSect, FC.vehicleBody, FC.ewSect);
    }

    calculateTotal();

});


// When the user updates the #month1 drop-down 
// Update FC.monthSect and assign FC.proratedPrice
$(document).on('change', '#month1', function() {

    // Reset to the defaults
    $("#month2").hide();
    $("#month3").hide();
    FC.monthSect = null;

    // ignore blank options
    if ($(this).val() == '') {
        calculateTotal();
        return;
    };

    var selecteduserBirthday = $(this).val();

    var paymentPlanDetails = FCUtils.getPaymentPlanDetailsBasedOnBirthMonth(selecteduserBirthday);
    var monthsToGo = paymentPlanDetails.monthsUntilBirthday;

    if (paymentPlanDetails.paymentPlan == "2or14months") {
        $("#month2").show();
    } else if (paymentPlanDetails.paymentPlan == "3or15months") {
        $("#month3").show();
    }

    // Assign FC.monthSect if monthSect = 4-12 | 1 | 13
    if (monthsToGo >= 4 && monthsToGo <= 12) {
        FC.monthSect = 4;
    } else if (monthsToGo == 1 || monthsToGo == 13) {
        FC.monthSect = 13;
    }

    FCUtils.getProratedFeeFromFeeList(FC.monthSect, FC.vehicleBody, FC.ewSect);
    calculateTotal();

});
```

*Note: You may have noticed that some the function names are prepended with `FCUtils`, which is an object I have attached all the "utility" functions to. You don't necessarily need to do this in your own program, you could just write your functions and call them like you normally would, but in my example app, I used a design pattern called [The Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript), which helps group common functionality, and is another step towards making code more readable.*

#### Step #02 : Query the `FC` object in `calculateTotal()`

Now that your form inputs are self-contained and they all know how to update their respective value on the `FC` object, all your `calculateTotal()` function needs to do is query is the `FC` object for values to calculate:

```
function calculateTotal() {

    var titleFees =     FC.rvPrice + 
                        FC.titlePrice + 
                        FC.lienPrice + 
                        FC.purchaseDatePrice + 
                        FC.IRFPrice + 
                        FC.proratedPrice + 
                        FC.specialFee;

    FC.totalPrice = titleFees;

    // Now you can update the browser with this data
    $("#totalPrice").text(titleFees);

}
```

Since the `calculateTotal()` function is called on every "change" event of your form, it's what gives your form that "live" feeling. You can also update other parts of your app from within this function.

You can **[review a jsfiddle where I put all these ideas into practice here](http://jsfiddle.net/cabguwdx/16/)**. I have added a HUD (The "Black Box" that appears in the upper right corner) which will give you a live snapshot of the data contained in the `FC` object at all times. If the HUD is in the way of things, simply "click to drag" it around the screen to move it out of the way.

Hope this helps! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track when you do not want to type a huge IF-ELSE by hand - esp if it gets repetitive. (you already have a missed a "0" in the last line, and sometimes it is ">" and sometimes ">=" :-).

What you can do is setup a method to save different thresholds and the value when the threshold is breached. So code not the use case but the algo.
You can even get more creative, for example change `this.get = function(wt)` to `this.get = function(wt, default_value)`
and plug in a default value. And so on.

```
var LevelFinder = function(){
    this.range = []; // always sorted when new values added
    this.add = function( over_wt, sel_value ) {
        this.range.push({over_wt:over_wt, sel_value:sel_value});
        this.range.sort(function(x,y){return x.over_wt - y.over_wt;});
    };
    this.get = function(wt){
        var x, i;
        for ( i = 0; i < this.range.length; ++i ) {
            if ( this.range[i].over_wt > wt ) {
                if ( i > 0 ) x = this.range[i-1].sel_value;
                return x;
            }
        }
        return this.range[i-1].sel_value;
    }
} ;
var ewFinder = new LevelFinder();
ewFinder.add(10000, 3);
ewFinder.add(20000, 5);
ewFinder.add(26000, 6);
ewFinder.add(15000, 4); // this is entered out of sequence but will get sorted by the adder

ewFinder.get(17000); // produces 4 in console
ewFinder.get(22000); // 5
ewFinder.get(0); // undefined
ewFinder.get(999000); // 6
```

HTH.